# Как динамически расширять массив объектов при нажатии на кнопку java?

Tags: java, массивы, динамические-массивы

У меня есть форма расчета ЗП и класс `Worker`.

```
public class Worker extends Object {
private String full_name;
private String position;
private int pay;

public Worker (String worker_full_name, String worker_position, int worker_pay){
    full_name = worker_full_name;
    position = worker_position;
    pay = worker_pay;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Я его импортировал и создал в классе формы поле массив `Worker-ов`

```
  private Worker [] workers = new Worker[1];
```

Теперь при нажатии на кнопку на форме я создаю новый объект класса `Worker`, получая его ФИО, должность и ЗП.

```
  Worker worker = new Worker(full_name_Text_Field.getText(),position_list_model.getSelectedItem().toString(),worker_pay);
```

Осталось только добавлять каждого `Worker` в массив. Можно ли это как-то сделать не создавая массив фиксированной размерности? Есть ли способы динамически расширять массив? Или как-то приспособить `java.util.list.*;` под хранение объектов?

В дальнейшем планируется с помощью этого массива реализовать удаление выделенных рабочих из списка ведомости и расчет ИТОГО.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
private List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();

workers.add(new Worker(...));
```

Внутри `ArrayList` автоматически будет расширятся при добавлении в него элементов, причем делая это довольно оптимально, поэтому при использовании `ArrayList`-ов вам не нужно будет думать об их изначальном размере.